# Bluemix Secure Gateway - Windows service fails to start, remains in paused status

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

OS: Windows 10

During the install of IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Windows client (ibm-securegateway-client-1.5.1+client_windows.exe), I checked the Windows Service install option:
"Please check this option if you would like the Secure Gateway Client to run as a service and restart automatically".

Checking services.msc I'm seeing "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service" has been registered as a client, but status is "Paused".
If I attempt to manually start it, I see a prompt:

> "Windows could not start the IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service
>   service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This
>   could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If
>   the problem persists, contact your system administrator."

Following the documentation at https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_053.html#sg_065 , I've attempted to un/install the Windows service manually.

Uninstall works fine with:
windowsService.cmd uninstall

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client

C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client>windowsService.cmd uninstall

> ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client@1.5.1 uninstall-securegw-service C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client
> winser -x -r -s --name "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"
```

On attempting to install I see the following output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client>windowsService.cmd install

> ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client@1.5.1 install-securegw-service C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client
> winser -i -a -s --name "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"

{ Error: Command failed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client\node_modules\winser\bin\nssm64.exe" start "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"
I B M   B l u e m i x   S e c u r e   G a t e w a y   S e r v i c e :   U n e x p e c t e d   s t a t u s   S E R V I C E _ P A U S E D   i n   r e s p o n s e   t o   S T A R T   c o n t r o l .

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:207:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Secure Gateway Client\\ibm\\securegateway\\client\\node_modules\\winser\\bin\\nssm64.exe" start "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service" ' }

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Secure Gateway Client\\ibm\\ibm-node-v6.2.1-win-x64\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Secure Gateway Client\\ibm\\ibm-node-v6.2.1-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "install-securegw-service"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client@1.5.1 install-securegw-service: `winser -i -a -s --name "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client@1.5.1 install-securegw-service script 'winser -i -a -s --name "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     winser -i -a -s --name "IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Service"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client\npm-debug.log

C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client>npm bugs ibm-bluemix-secure-gateway-client
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client>
```

I'm not seeing any npm-debug.log file generated.

Log information doesn't shed much light:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Secure Gateway Client\ibm\securegateway\client\logs

```
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
****************************************************************Starting Windows Service************************************************************************ 
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
****************************************************************Starting Windows Service************************************************************************ 
****************************************************************Windows Service stopped************************************************************************ 
*************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
****************************************************************Starting Windows Service************************************************************************ 
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
****************************************************************Starting Windows Service************************************************************************
```

I've tried stripping securegw_service.config back to the bare minimal (I think), containing just:

```
GATEWAY_ID=xxx
SECTOKEN=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest update to Windows 10 has caused the installation to fail.  We've confirmed on our own systems and will look to see if we can identify any work-arounds until a proper fix is available.